# call a method one time With a CADisplayLink

Tags: iphone, xcode, methods, if-statement, timer

So I have a method with a CADisplayLink on it.In this method I have :

```
 if (leScore % 1000 == 0) { 
            //call a method one time        
 }
```

I would like to call a method one time if  % 1000 == 0, my problem is that as there is a CADisplayLink on my method I can't call just one time another method when  % 1000 == 0(it call the method   at 60fps).How can I solve this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: Damn you internet, I loled at `le score`...

Answer (score 1):

Just make a boolean variable to check if the method is called already or not. Set it to NO, then modify the if block like this:

```
if (!isMyMethodCalled && leScore % 1000 == 0) {
 isMyMethodCalled = YES;
// and call the method
}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. I call my method with [self mymethod] like that ? but it doesn't change

Comment: just make a boolean variable. set it initially to NO, then set it to YES if you called the function. and before you call the function just check if you called it already or not (by checking if the boolean variable is YES or NO).